# How to use xsl templates and recursion to build a new xml document?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I would like to know how to use xsl templates to transform my xml document to another xml document **with original element hierarchy.** I would also like to add some attributes to elements in the new generated XML.

My original XML file looks something like this:

```
<shop> 
  <product>
    <cookie ID="001">
    <price>2</price>
    </cookie>
  </product>

  <product>
    <bread ID="002">
    <price>5</price>
    </bread>
  </product>

  <product>
    <milk ID="003">
    <price>2</price>
    </milk>
  </product>
</shop>
```

I would like to transform this to following XML:

```
<newXML> 
  <newElement>
    <newElement ID="001">
    <newElement price="2"/>
    </newElement>
  </newElement>

  <newElement>
    <newElement ID="002">
    <newElement price="5"/>
    </newElement>
  </newElement>

  <newElement>
    <newElement ID="003">
    <newElement price="2"/>
    </newElement>
  </newElement>
</newXML>
```

What would be a good way to do this? Can this be done using recursion with templates or is there some better way? I've been trying to use following logic:

1. make a template that creates an element
2. read current elements ID if it exist and put it to newElement
3. if current element has a child, apply this template to it (some kind of recursion)

Despite of many attempts I haven't been able to make this work. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you would build upon the XSLT Identity Transform, which is a very common design pattern in XSLT. To start with you just have a template that copies the elements and outputs them exactly as-is]

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

What you then do is add extra templates to match your elements, and add codes to rename them, or add attributes as required. For example, to rename the root element you would add the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="shop">
  <newXML>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </newXML>
</xsl:template>
```

You don't have to use specific element names here either. If you wanted to rename and element with an **ID** attribute to the same name, you could do something like this

```
<xsl:template match="product/*[@ID]">
   <newElement>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </newElement>
</xsl:template>
```

And in the case of your **price** element, if you wanted to create an attribute based on the element's text content, you could add a template like so:

```
<xsl:template match="price">
   <newElement price="{.}" />
</xsl:template>
```

(Note, this uses **Attribute Value Templates** to create the attribute here. THis is usually preferred to using **xsl:attribute**)

Try this XML for starters:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="shop">
      <newXML>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </newXML>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="product">
      <newElement>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </newElement>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="product/*[@ID]">
      <newElement>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </newElement>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="price">
      <newElement price="{.}" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs the following:

```
<newXML>
   <newElement>
      <newElement ID="001">
         <newElement price="2"/>
      </newElement>
   </newElement>
   <newElement>
      <newElement ID="002">
         <newElement price="5"/>
      </newElement>
   </newElement>
   <newElement>
      <newElement ID="003">
         <newElement price="2"/>
      </newElement>
   </newElement>
</newXML>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detailed answer. All seems to be working as far as i've been testing exept <xsl:template match="product/*[@ID]">
   <newElement>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </newElement>
</xsl:template> I guess the problem has something to do with "product/*[@ID]" . I keep getting following error: runtime error: file transform.xsl line 47 element copy
Attribute nodes must be added before any child nodes to an element. Anyway your answer was very valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you just want to transform the document, so why not try  XQuery instead of XSLT? It is much simpler..

You just write the xml you want to create and `{..}` if you want to insert something there from the input file and `for $variable in //xpath` to repeat it with the part of the input file matched by the xpath expression.

So this creates the desired xml file:

```
<newXML>{
  for $prod in /shop/product/* return
    <newElement>
      <newElement>{
        $prod/@ID,
        for $value in $prod/* return 
          <newElement price="{$value}"/>
      }</newElement>
    </newElement>
}</newXML>
```